# Center children in GridPane using CSS

Tags: css, javafx, alignment, gridpane

[image]

I have a `GridPane` populated with `ToggleButtons`. First row and column in that `GridPane` holds `Text` object labels.
I am unable to center the `Text` objects with the `ToggleButton`s so the text appears in the middle, **using css**.
(This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35438985/3992939) shows how to achieve it by using `GridPane.setHalignment(node, HPos.CENTER);`).

MCVE if needed :

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Node;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.ToggleButton;
import javafx.scene.layout.GridPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.Pane;
import javafx.scene.text.Text;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class GridTest extends Application {

    private static final int COLS = 5, ROWS = 3;

    @Override public void start(Stage stage) {
        Scene scene = new Scene(makeGrid());
        scene.getStylesheets().add(getClass().
                getResource("GridTest.css").toExternalForm());
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
    }

    private Pane makeGrid() {

        GridPane grid = new GridPane();

        for(int rowIndex = 0; rowIndex < ROWS ; rowIndex++) {

            Node[] nodes = new Node[COLS];
            Node node;
            for(int colIndex = 0; colIndex < COLS ; colIndex++) {

                if (rowIndex == 0){ //col header;
                    String txt =  (colIndex == 0) ?
                            " " : String.valueOf(colIndex);
                    node = new Text(txt);
                }else if (colIndex == 0){//row header
                    node = new Text(String.valueOf(rowIndex));
                }else {
                    node= new ToggleButton();
                }
                nodes[colIndex]= node;
            }
            grid.addRow(rowIndex, nodes);
        }
        return grid;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Application.launch(args);
    }
  }
```

CSS:

```
Text{
    -fx-text-alignment: center;
}

GridPane {
    -fx-hpos:center ;
    -fx-hgap: 5;
    -fx-vgap: 5;
    -fx-padding:10;  
}

ToggleButton {  
    -fx-pref-width:30;
}
```

Comment: See [docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/javafx/scene/text/Text.html#textAlignmentProperty): "Note: In the case of a single line of text, where the width of the node is determined by the width of the text, the alignment setting has no effect.". You can use a label and set the `alignment` (not the `textAlignment`) to center in CSS, but you will still need to configure the grid pane in Java to allow the label to grow to fill the grid pane cell. Typically, you should use JavaFX CSS to manage *style*, not *layout* (though the boundary between the two is blurred sometimes).

Comment: @James_D thanks for your quick response. I am aware of it. I saw it in some of your answers here. In this case the need is center the `Text` object within the `Gridpane` columns (not to center the text within the `Text` control). I can easily demonstrate a solution using `GridPane.setHalignment(node, HPos.CENTER)` . I am looking for a CSS solution.

Comment: As I said, this is a misuse of CSS in JavaFX. Don't try to use CSS for layout: you should use either Java or FXML for that.

Comment: @James_D I see your point. Isn't that what `-fx-hpos:center ;`  is for ?

Comment: I'm not aware of that property: it isn't listed in the [CSS docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/javafx/scene/doc-files/cssref.html) as far as I can tell. If it did anything, I would imagine it set the position of the entire grid pane's content within the space allocated to the grid pane by its parent, should that space be larger than the space the grid pane needed.

Comment: It shows under some [Panes](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17802_01/javafx/javafx/1.3/docs/api/javafx.scene/doc-files/cssref.html#vbox) , Labeled and a few more.

Comment: That's JavaFX 1.x documentation. That's been deprecated for about 8 years. It is not present in the [current version](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/javafx/scene/doc-files/cssref.html#vbox) (JavaFX 10). It's superseded by `-fx-alignment` (which sets both the horizontal and vertical alignment), and does as I described (sets the alignment of the entire content of the pane, not the alignment within each cell of the grid pane).

Comment: `Text` nodes are non resizable. You cannot set `static` properties via css either. This means your only option with css only is center aligning every child using `fx-alignment: center;` on the `GridPane`. Other than that you cannot anything, unless you replace the `Text` nodes with `Label`s and increase the max size to large enough values and then centering the `Label` text...

Comment: I think even if you set the max size of a label, it won't actually grow to the size of the cell without `GridPane.setFillWidth(label, true)` (I don't believe that's the default), and, as pointed out, there's no way to set a static property in CSS.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on the comments posted by @ James_D and @fabian and previous answers there are two options to get the text labels centered. 
One option, as posted in the question, does not use css. It requires slight modification of the `makeGrid`:

```
//see: https://stackoverflow.com/a/35438985/3992939
GridPane.setHalignment(node, HPos.CENTER);  //added line
nodes[colIndex]= node;
```

This solutions does not change the (non resizable) `Text`. It simple centers it within its `GridPane` parent column.

The other option involves changing the `Text` lables to `Labels` :

```
private Pane makeGrid() {

    GridPane grid = new GridPane();
    for(int rowIndex = 0; rowIndex < ROWS ; rowIndex++) {

        Node[] nodes = new Node[COLS];
        Node node;
        for(int colIndex = 0; colIndex < COLS ; colIndex++) {
            if (rowIndex == 0){ //col header;
                String txt =  (colIndex == 0) ? " " : String.valueOf(colIndex);
                node = new Label(txt);                      //** changed 
            }else if (colIndex == 0){//row header
                node = new Label(String.valueOf(rowIndex)); //** changed 
            }else {
                node= new ToggleButton();
            }
            nodes[colIndex]= node;
        }
        grid.addRow(rowIndex, nodes);
    }
    return grid;
}
```

And using css (or additional code) to set the label's width to maximum and center the text :

```
GridPane .label{
    -fx-alignment: center;
    -fx-max-width: Infinity;
}

GridPane {
    -fx-hgap: 5;
    -fx-vgap: 5;
    -fx-padding:10;  
}

ToggleButton {  
    -fx-pref-width:30;
}
```

[image]