# Add action to GridPane in scene builder

Tags: java, events, javafx, scenebuilder, gridpane

I have a image_1, Title_1 and details_1, in a GridPane_1 as one,([see the picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/29yHn.png)).
I want to add an event to the GridPane_1 so if you enter the mouse to the GridPane_1 becomes a gray color background(for example), to denote the selection of the image_1, Title_1 and details_1 one thing as one button so if you press it takes it to the window_1, the same for the remaining
(GridPane_2 (image_2, Title_2 and details_2) --- window_2)
(GridPane_3 (image_3, Title_3 and details_3) --- window_3)
(GridPane_4 (image_4, Title_4 and details_4) --- window_4)

Comment: Ok. So what is the question? What’s stopping you doing that?

Comment: for the change  background  part you can give  css style class  like gridpane to the four grids children  and  use a stylesheet file

Comment: thank you, your answer to change css help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can give a style class to all four children gridpanes . In SceneBuilder there is a css javafx menu under inspector>>properties . In this case "gridpane" .

[image: style class scenebuilder]

Now you need to attach this css file to the tab preview>>Scene Style Sheets >>Add Style Sheet
I've named it main.css , but you can name it whatever you want .

main.css  file :

```
 .gridpane:hover {

-fx-background-color : blue;
}
```

Now `hover`  is a pseudoclass that apply its rules only when the mouse is over the node . In this case it will change background color to blue . You can see it in scenebuilder in preview>> Show Preview in Window.

[image]

Css has been applied in sceneBuilder only . If you want to set this style in the actual app follow  [How to style the GridPane using CSS in JavaFx](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61972602/how-to-style-the-gridpane-using-css-in-javafx)