# Javafx GridPane, how to center Node? (Text/Label)

Tags: java, javafx

I am trying to learn Javafx for a class I am taking. I am having a lot of difficulty transitioning from HTML + ERB templates to the Javafx framework (I am a Rails dev).

For some reason I am unable to center a Label node in a gridpane. Here is my `start` method:

```
@Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {
        GridPane root = new GridPane();
        FlowPane leftbanner = new FlowPane();

        leftbanner.setPrefWidth(200);
        String bgStyle = "-fx-background-color: lightblue;"
                         + "-fx-background-radius: 0%;"
                         + "-fx-background-inset: 5px;";
        leftbanner.setStyle(bgStyle);

        root.add(leftbanner, 0, 0, 1, 1);
        root.add(createGridPane(), 1, 0, 1, 1);

        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 700, 500);
        stage.setTitle("Recommendify");
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
    }
```

I am using the `createGridPane` method to build my app. Here are the contents of that method which includes my attempts to center the label:

```
public GridPane createGridPane() {
        GridPane grid = new GridPane();
        grid.setPadding(new Insets(10));
        grid.setHgap(10);
        grid.setVgap(10);

        Text txt = new Text("Recommendify");
        txt.setFont(Font.font("Dialog", FontWeight.BOLD, 12));
        GridPane.setHalignment(txt, HPos.CENTER);

        grid.add(txt, 0, 0, 1, 1);
        grid.add(new Separator(), 0, 1, 3, 1);

        return grid;
}
```

I have also tried these solutions posted here: [JavaFX alignment of Label in GridPane](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35438104/javafx-alignment-of-label-in-gridpane/35438985#35438985)

Do I need to throw this Label node into a container in order to center it in the GridPane? Like an HBox or VBox?

Comment: Incidentally, your question mentions a `Label` node, but your code is using a `Text` node. The result is going to be the same either way, but you may want to [edit] the question to avoid confusion.

Comment: You are using `GridPane` alright. But, Do you know how many columns and/rows are there in the grid (grid means rows and columns, in general). So, figure how many rows/columns, and then where you want your label/text. BTW, `Label` and `Text` have different purposes. A label is used to make a static text and a `Text` is used for creating text which can change during the course of the application - like _a status bar text_. To align a `Label` within a grid pane's cell, use: `GridPane.setHalignment(labelToBeCentered, javafx.geometry.HPos.CENTER);`.

Comment: Also, it looks like you are creating a grid pane within a grid pane - (1) `GridPane root = new GridPane();` in the `start`, and (2) in the `createGridPane()` adding it to the `root`: `root.add(createGridPane(), 1, 0, 1, 1);` .

Comment: Here are examples of using various layouts: [JavaFX: Working with Layouts](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/layout-tutorial/index.html).

Comment: @prasad_ - I believe they actually intend to have 2 GridPanes, one within the other.

Comment: @Zephyr I don't see any indication of requiring two grid panes in the code -or- in the requirement (what kind of application is this? What is the intended form?). To me, from the post comments it looks like the OP is trying out JavaFX newly.

Comment: The `createGridPane()` has a missing `return grid;` statement.

Answer (score 4):

There is actually nothing wrong with your code. The "Recommendify" text **is** centered in its cell. However, the cell is no wider than the text itself.

You can see this by turning on the grid lines within your `createGridPane()` method:

```
grid.setGridLinesVisible(true);
```

[image: screenshot]

---

To test the alignment, you can add `ColumnConstraints` to the `GridPane`:

```
grid.getColumnConstraints().add(new ColumnConstraints(150));
```

The above statement sets the preferred width of the first column to `150`. Here is the new result:

[image: screenshot 2]

As you can see, the `Text` node is centered properly.

> **EDIT:** *Keep in mind that if you want your `Text` to be centered over the `Separator` you've added to the second row, you need to have
>   it span 3 columns as well.*